# SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred when signing Excel files

Tags: excel, vba, certificate, code-signing, signtool

I have already installed the required DLLs using regsrv.exe and tested it in two different environments. I can sign VBS files, but I am having trouble finding information on the error message I am receiving when trying to sign an Excel file with VBA macros.

I tried it with and without the offsign.bat

Here is the command I am using:

```
.\offsign.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\" "sign /debug /f C:\Temp\officesign\dateien\codesignedcert.pfx /p password /fd SHA256 C:\Temp\officesign\dateien\SelfSignedTest.xlsm"
```

And here is the error message I receive:

> The following additional certificates will be attached: Done Adding
> Additional Store SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has
> occurred. Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed."
> (-2147220493/0x800403f3)
>
> =================================== Job Summary ==================================== Error! Failed when executing the first sign command. You should fix the problem and re-run OffSign.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This error may appear if the xlsm file doesn't contain a vbaProject.bin entry